# GH-Pages only loads index.html but AngularJS and othe

Tags: html, angularjs, github, github-pages

I tried making a GH-Page for my AngularJS project http://cmittle.github.io/ptcalc1/, from my repo https://github.com/cmittle/ptcalc1.  When I load the GH-Page I see the `index.html`.  The header and footers are stored in separate html files and do not load.  I've used the `ng-view` AngularJS directive to load the content of the tabs from other html files and the url changes accordingly, but the html pages do not load.

The code works when launched from either Brackets or Netbeans.

Comment: Did you use the code inspector ? 404 + angular error

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have a gh-pages branch for that repo.

Go to the settings tab in that repo, then options, and click 'Launch automatic page generator'. Alternatively, you can create the gh-page yourself, just read [read the docs](https://pages.github.com) on how to do so.